# Plone full text indexing Excel files

Tags: excel, full-text-search, plone, xls

how can I customize Plone search engine in order to actvate full text indexing of excel files?  I have already installed pdftotext and wv for pdf, word files full text indexing.

Comment: Did you try Products.TextIndexNG3 already? It claims to support formats of the dying monopol.

Comment: Try ftw.tika. imho it's much better than anything else for plone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add [Products.OpenXml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.OpenXml) to your instance eggs and install it in Plone you can index modern Office formats, at least .docx and .xlsx.  For plain old Excel (.xls) files this does not work.

I tried it in a Plone 4.3.2 buildout config a few weeks ago:

```
[instance]
eggs =
    ...
    Products.OpenXml

[versions]
# You need a more recent lxml than default Plone, some 3.x version
lxml = 3.3.3
Products.OpenXml = 1.1.1
```

Alternatively or additionally, use [Products.AROfficeTransforms](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.AROfficeTransforms).  I have only tried it in combination with Products.OpenXml, but Products.AROfficeTransforms on its own is sufficient if you are only interested in old-style excel sheets, .xls.  In a buildout config:

```
[instance]
eggs =
    ...
    Products.AROfficeTransforms

[versions]
Products.AROfficeTransforms = 0.11.0
```

It requires the xlhtml binary to be installed on your system.  This is an ancient binary, last changed in 2002.  I did not try to install it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`ftw.tika`](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.tika)

Supported formats:

- Microsoft Office formats (Office Open XML)
- *.docx Word Documents
- *.dotx Word Templates
- *.xlsx Excel Sheets
- *.xltx Excel Templates
- *.pptx Powerpoint Presentations
- *.potx Powerpoint Templates
- *.ppsx Powerpoint Slideshows
- Legacy Microsoft Office (97) formats
- Rich Text Format
- OpenOffice ODF formats
- OpenOffice 1.x formats
- Common Adobe formats (InDesign, Illustrator, Photoshop)
- PDF documents
- WordPerfect documents
  E-Mail messages

It's based on apache tika and runs as a service managed by supervisor (You have to extend your buildout).

It's integrated with portal_transforms, is well tested and documented.

More infos:

- Release on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftw.tika/1.1.1)