# Index LibreOffice / OpenOffice files for full text search in Plone5

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I'm trying to have Plone 5 index  LibreOffice / OpenOffice documents, ods, odt and odp, to be found via full text search. With OpenXml-1.2.1 Docx &Co is working, PDFs do work, too.

Are there any guidelines, what to do, what to install?

Products/PortalTransforms seems to support office_uno, so I run a headless soffice '--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp' --norestore --nofirststartwizard --nologo --headless
but port 2002 is never triggered.

I also do not see the office_uno transform in Plone/portal_transforms . The LibreOffice MIME types are present.

I'm using
    Plone 5.0.6rc1 (5016)
    CMF 2.2.10
    Zope 2.13.24
    Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) [GCC 4.9.2]
    PIL 3.3.1 (Pillow)

Comment: We use `ftw.tika` to index all kind of file data. It supports nearly everything. I already answered this question here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151319/plone-full-text-indexing-excel-files/23264996#23264996 . It's not tested on Plone 5, but it may work out of the box, since the only thing it does is to register a portal_transform, which uses apache tika.

Comment: Not sure but probably AROfficeTransform is still a valid choice (but it seems not so interesting as ftw.tika is)

Comment: Similar to the existing [pdf_to_text][1] transform you can register your own  transform using the [odt2txt binary][2] (install it on your server i.e. with `apt install odt2txt``). 

This does only transform documents, but not spreadsheets and other openoffice/libreoffice formats.

  [1]: https://github.com/plone/Products.PortalTransforms/blob/master/Products/PortalTransforms/transforms/pdf_to_text.py
  [2]: https://github.com/dstosberg/odt2txt

Comment: I found ftw.tika heavy to install, but I never tried it .

Comment: AROfficeTransform does not help, unfortunately. Internally this egg seems to use xsltproc, which is never started. The MIME type of the extension ods is the same as the MIME Type of transform oo2_to_html. So, I'm lost here. No error message I see.

Comment: @JensW.Klein: I've got it working with odt2txt. How do I add a new transform best? I patched AROfficeTransforms to include my transform only ... .

Comment: @ska If you don't use tika as service, it's absolutely simple to install. Add dependency + install profile. The disadvantage is, that it has to start tika for every single transform, thus there is a buildout config, which gives you a ./bin/tika-server to start a tika service. I know this is a little bit self-advertising ;-) But if you have trouble to install it, I'm happy to help.